# GetUpperBound() always returns zero

Tags: vb.net

Why is intLength = dblFileArray.GetUpperBound(0) always returning 0?  I commented out the rest of the program that uses dblFileArray and created a textbox that displays dblFileArray's value for troubleshooting purposes. **I understand i can use List but i want to use an array instead.**

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    ' stores the contents of the numbers.txt file in an array
    ' increases by 1 each number stored in the array
    ' writes the array contents to the file
    Dim dblFileArray(0) As Double
    Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader
    Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter = Nothing
    Dim intLength As Integer
    lstNumbers.Items.Clear()

    inFile = IO.File.OpenText("Numbers.txt")
    Do Until inFile.Peek = -1
        Dim index As Integer = 0

        Double.TryParse(inFile.ReadLine, dblFileArray(index))
        dblFileArray(index) += 1
        lstNumbers.Items.Add(dblFileArray(index).ToString)
        ReDim Preserve dblFileArray(index)
        index += 1
    Loop

    inFile.Close()

    intLength = dblFileArray.GetUpperBound(0)
    txtBox.Text = intLength.ToString
    'outFile = IO.File.CreateText("Numbers.txt")
    ' For index As Integer = 0 To intLength
    '
    'outFile.WriteLine(dblFileArray(index))
    '   index += 1
    '  Next

    'outFile.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use a `List(Of Integer)` instead of an array?

Comment: Because i need to use an array.  I would use list but i need to find out what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're declaring the index = 0 inside the loop, so the value will be always the same. Declare it before the loop begins and increment it at the end of the while loop.
You should only use arrays with a fix length. Redim it's not a good choice since has a poor performance. If you need a dynamic array go for a list, arraylist or whatever. They will avoid you a lot of headaches.

Comment: but if the loop adds the values to the array, wouldnt the array keep the values outside the loop regardless?

Comment: Your array is not growing. It has only 1 element. That's why upper bound is always 0

Comment: In every while the initialization has to be outside, before.

Comment: I moved it now its tellin me Index was outside the bounds of the array.  i dont see why if im still incrementing index...

Comment: if the array is not large enough, the index will be outside the bounds **because** you increment it.  The 1980s called - they want their arrays back.  If you dont want to use a List, use an ArrayList - this wont happen because they grow as you add to them.

Comment: The line redim preserve it's wrong you're suppose to add 1, redim preserve array(index + 1) or put that line after the index increments. anyway working with arrays is not safe. It's easy to make a mistake. Use a list, arraylist or whatever fits your needs.

Comment: haha Plutonix cracked me up, yeah dont know why they teach us arrays when we can just use lists.  But thanks guys this was a great help.

Comment: Arrays are important they are the base of all of the lists, collections etc but. You should only use them when they have a fix size.